# Subspace of a Normed Space

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X_1$ be a closed subspace and $X_2$ be a finite dimensional subspace of a normed space X. Then $X_1+X_2$ is closed in $X$.

I have this problem in my Homework list. My question is if I can used Cauchy sequences? Because I know that the subspace are closed... Then all Cauchy sequence converge at a element of set?

Comment: Please follow the guidelines outlined by [How to ask a good question?](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) and [How to ask a homework question?](https://goo.gl/Fyfb22). Low quality questions run the risk of being [closed](https://goo.gl/J58Qwn) and [deleted](https://goo.gl/FmJes1), and repeated closures and deletions may trigger a [question ban](https://goo.gl/7QcTa9). Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prove this result then one easy way to prove this is using definition of quotient space.
Since $X_1$ is a closed subspace of normed space $X$ then you can define the quotient space $X/X_1$ and take the map $\pi: X\rightarrow X/X_1$ as $\pi(x)=x+X_1$ then since $X_2$ is given to be finite dimensional hence $\pi(X_2)$ is again of finite dimensional and hence is closed in $X/X_1$ then by definition of $\pi$ we will have $X_1+X_2=\pi^{-1}(\pi(X_2))$ is closed in X.

Comment: Thanks, I think that this was more intuitive...

Comment: Question: How prove that $X_1+X_2=\pi^{-1}(\pi(X_2))$? Okay, I understand that the image inverse of a closed set is a closed set, by Theorem, but $\pi^{-1}(\pi(X_2))=X_2$? Then $X_1+X_2=X_2$?

Comment: you can check that $\pi(X_1+X_2)=X_1+X_2$ because $X_1$ is a subspace of $X$.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use Cauchy sequences, because even if you know that a certain sequence of elements of $X_1+X_2$ is a Cauchy sequence, you cannot deduce from that fact that it converges.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot think Cauchy sequences.

We know that normed spaces are metric spaces with the induced metric $d(x,y) = \|x-y\|$, and in metric spaces, in order to show that a subset is closed, we only have to show that every convergent sequence in the subset has limit point in it.